# How to print colored spaces and close the color code right after A?

Tags: c, printing, colors, space, xterm

Could anyone tell me how to print colored spaces using C on an xterm?
All I could end up printing was colored letters, but no matter how i try, i cant get it to print a colored space.

---

```
id_print_str("\033[22;31m A")
```

---

I cant get the above thing to print a color if the A was to be replaced by a space. yet I dont know how to close it in order not to change the whole xterm color.

Comment: Change it back to what it was before. How do you find out what it was before? No idea. Probably you should just set it to some "default" colour at the beginning then use that.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
/* Print the red block. */
printf("\033[;41m \n");

/* Reset terminal. */
printf("\033[0;m");
```

There's a nice and short linuxgazette article about this: [The mysterious `^[[` characters](http://linuxgazette.net/issue65/padala.html).

Comment: but whether I reset it, will it keep the A colored? and does it work this way? 
    printf("\033[;41m \033[0;m")

Comment: @Slrs Why don't you just try it :-) "Reset" means everything that follows will be printed as usual.

Comment: @cnicutar @ Seth Carnegie Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might use the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) library. For a single colored space it could be overkill, but if you want to make a complex terminal application it should be the right tool.